# IO error when deserializing continuation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script that was working well. But, today, I got an strange error: `IO error when deserializing continuation`. It's the only msg shown in my transcript (without refering to the line where I could get a clue about what is producing this error. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error simply disapeared (without I doing nothing to change the code).

Comment: I have seen this error a few times and the only logical conclusion that I could come up with is that at the moment you were executing a script, there was a server problem on Google's end, and it was not a problem with your code. My basis for this assumption is that when the script is run with the debugger, it produces a different error which is something like "A server error occurred, please try again later."